# Как сделать что бы нельзя было ввести прошлый месяц этого года: но можно было вводить любой месяц в следующем году

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Как сделать что бы нельзя было ввести прошлый месяц этого года: но можно было вводить любой месяц в следующем году

```
    function setYearToInput(){
  var date = new Date();
  var year = date.getYear() - 100;
  $('#expire_year').attr('min', year);
}

function setMonthToInput(){
  var date = new Date();
  var month = date.getMonth()+1;
  $('#date').attr('min', month);
}
```

вот html

```
<input required type="number" min="1" max="12" maxlength="2" class="form-control silver error" id="expire_month" name="expiry_month" data-infobox="Срок действия карты - месяц и год, указанные на лицевой стороне вашей банковской карты" placeholder="01">
                        <span class="expire-delimiter">/</span>
                        <input type="number" maxlength="2" class="form-control silver error" id="expire_year" name="expiry_year" data-infobox="Срок действия карты - месяц и год, указанные на лицевой стороне вашей банковской карты" placeholder="18" min="" max="99" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/iliyazelenko/pen/pZGbKV?editors=1010

```js
let now = new Date()
let year = now.getFullYear() - 2000
let month = now.getMonth() + 1

$('#expire_month, #expire_year').on('change', check)
$('.button-submit').click(submit)

$('#expire_year').attr('min', year)
$('#expire_month').attr('min', month)

function check () {
  let yearInput = $('#expire_year').val()
  let monthInput = $('#expire_month').val()
  if (yearInput === '' || monthInput === '')
return
  
  if (+yearInput === year) {
$('#expire_month').attr('min', month)
  } else {
$('#expire_month').attr('min', 1)
  }

  // если выбран текущий год и если выбирается месяц меньше текущего
  let yearBad = +yearInput < year
  if (yearBad) {
alert('Ошибка года')
// $('#expire_month').val(month) 
// $('#expire_year').val(year)
return false
  }
  if ((+yearInput === year && +monthInput < month)) {
alert('Ошибка месяца')
return false
  }

  return true
}

function submit () {
  // если не введен год или месяц
  if ($('#expire_year').val() === '' || $('#expire_month').val() === '') {
alert('Вы не ввели')
return false
  }

  if (check()) {
alert('Все ок!')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input required type="number" min="1" max="12" maxlength="2" class="form-control silver error" id="expire_month" name="expiry_month" data-infobox="Срок действия карты - месяц и год, указанные на лицевой стороне вашей банковской карты" placeholder="01">
                    <span class="expire-delimiter">/</span>
                    <input type="number" maxlength="2" class="form-control silver error" id="expire_year" name="expiry_year" data-infobox="Срок действия карты - месяц и год, указанные на лицевой стороне вашей банковской карты" placeholder="18" value="" required>
<button class="button-submit">Отправить</button>
```

Comment: Не проходит проверку по вашему примеру

Comment: Код по ссылке у меня работает. Или Вам все-таки нужно чтобы и для прошлых годов ошибку выдавало? Переделал код по ссылке.

Comment: нужно что бы когда я сабмител форму, то шла проверка если выбран 07-18 выдавало ошибку 

и что бы можно было вписывать любой месяц в будущем году

Comment: Проверьте, сейчас все должно работать.

Comment: На кодепен я немогу ничего ввести))) оно сразу отрабатывает ошибку)

Comment: Теперь все работает божественно, я старался, если еще найдете ошибку то я себя грохну))

Comment: у вас ошибки вылетают при нажатие на поле инпутов) нельзя ввести с помощю клавы, только нужно стрелочками выберать числа)

Comment: Там просто событие такое, если Вам удобней по другому, то я переделал. Хоть плюсаните мой ответ, я же старался)

Comment: Все бы ничего) но мне нжуно что бы год был с 2 чисел тоисть 18 19 а не из 4=)

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько `.val(year - 2000)`, держитесь, я за вас болею!

Comment: + немонятно почему значение автоматом подставляются

Comment: Я вообще не пишу на jquery уже 2 года, вместо этого на фреймворка, а вынужден это делать))

Comment: @СергійЧуйко переделал

Comment: Спасибо) я сделал по своему))) 

function newValidYear(){
  var now = new Date();
  var year = now.getYear() - 100;
  var month = now.getMonth()+1;

  var inputYear = $('#expire_year').val();
  console.log(inputYear, year, inputYear == year);
  if(inputYear == year){
    $('#date').attr('min', month)
  }
  else{
    $('#date').attr('min', 1);
  }
}

Comment: Ок, удачи с кодом, а почему у Вас `now.getYear() - 100` а не -2000?

Answer (score 1):

http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml5/formy/kalendar

Пример 2. Ограничение даты

```js
var calendar = calendar ||
  document.getElementById('calendar')

let d = new Date().toLocaleDateString().split('.').reverse()
d[2] = '01'
calendar.min = d.join('-')
console.log(calendar.min)
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="date" id="calendar" name="calendar" min="2012-05-29">
  <input type="submit" value="батон">
</form>
```

---

### вариант с двумя инпутами `type="number"`

```js
var expire_year = expire_year ||
  document.getElementById('expire_year')
var expire_month = expire_month ||
  document.getElementById('expire_month')

var dateObj = new Date();
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
// var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

expire_year.value = null
expire_year.min = year - 2000
expire_year.onfocus = function() {
  expire_month.value = null
}
expire_month.onfocus = function() {
  if (expire_year.value === expire_year.min) {
    expire_month.value = null
    expire_month.min = month
  } else {
    expire_month.value = null
    expire_month.min = 0
  }
}
```

```html
<input required type="number" maxlength="2" class="form-control silver error" id="expire_year" name="expiry_year" data-infobox="Срок действия карты - месяц и год, указанные на лицевой стороне вашей банковской карты" placeholder="18" min="" max="99">
<span class="expire-delimiter">/</span>
<input required type="number" min="1" max="12" maxlength="2" class="form-control silver error" id="expire_month" name="expiry_month" data-infobox="Срок действия карты - месяц и год, указанные на лицевой стороне вашей банковской карты" placeholder="01">
```

Comment: у меня ругается на вот этот кусок кода 
calendar.min = d.join('-')

Comment: в броузере ругается. аль в ide. чем кроет?

Comment: у вас указано 

min="2012-05-29"

у меня другая структура html

Comment: у вас получается: что все в 1 инпуте проверку делает
а у меня 2 разных на месяц и на год! 
поэтому ваш вариант не походит мне(

Comment: http://prntscr.com/khya3k 
вот ошибка

Comment: @СергійЧуйко, __upd__: _вариант с двумя инпутами type="number"_

Comment: у вас немного не так)  все хорошо, но человек может ввести вручку 07 и тогда ваша проверка не работает: у меня нету стрелочек что бы можно выберать дату: у меня все вручную прописывать нужно и когда вводиш на клавиатуре число 06 то оно позовляет ввести

Comment: ок, а если попробовать отправить? 06. покажет предупреждение?

Comment: у меня с вашим 2 вариантом вообще почему то ламается логика,  перестают работать друие функции(